# Any update on a replacement for IBM Analytics for Hadoop on Bluemix?

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, biginsights

Is there any update on a replacement service for IBM Analytics for Hadoop on Bluemix? I understand the service was decommissioned in February and a beta for a replacement is in the works. I am a member of the IBM Academic Initiative who was planning on using this service for a course starting in May, and I and my university's academic IT group are concerned that we have no news on whether an equivalent service will be available by then. Can anyone provide updates or advice? Are there alternative cloud-based Hadoop services we should be considering? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Analytics for Apache Hadoop BETA service has been replaced by the [Biginsights for Apache Hadoop](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/biginsights-for-apache-hadoop/) service. It is basically an updated and expanded version of the Analytics for Apache Hadoop project. Regarding the BETA replacement you can register to the IBM BigInsights On Cloud Basic Plan BETA [here](http://www2.cloudant.com/biginsights-on-cloud-paygo-beta).

Comment: Thanks. I thought the BigInsights for Apache Hadoop was for "production" use and didn't have a free option--the only plan I saw there was "Enterprise." Do you know, is there a free tier on BigInsights for Academic Cloud users?

Answer (score 0):

An update ...

We have now introduced a beta plan under BigInsights for Apache Hadoop, on Bluemix, which will now let you spin up IBM Open Platform clusters with open source Apache Hadoop and Apache Spark. This is free to use in the beta period. Please refer to this [blog](http://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/blog/introducing-biginsights-apache-hadoop-basic-plan-bluemix) for more information and context on this update.